# Cannot Build APK

Tags: android, jar, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to build APK. But i am facing the error. But i can run this directly using USB debugging.

```
Error:12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.starmicronics.starioextension.commandbuilder.c) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.starmicronics.starioextension.commandbuilder.d) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
12:16:10.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}

12:16:10.235 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:16:10.235 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a library (looks like `com.starmicronics...`) that has been created in an incorrect way.

You can either recompile the library yourself from source if this is available, or otherwise, you should be able to prevent the warning by adding the following to your proguard configuration file:

```
-dontwarn com.starmicronics.starioextension.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is occurred due to inappropriate `dependencies`, i mean maybe  you didn't set the `dependencies` or `libraries` properly. please check them once.

Comment: i am using a library, there is a problem i think . see the lines "(com.starmicronics.starioextension.commandbuilder.c)

Comment: i don't know about this library also i didn't use this library ever..sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I just reverted to the older gradle plugins (gradle:2.1.3 and gradle-experimental:0.7.3) and it fixed the issue for me.